# ¿Como puedo insertar objetos al vector y como puedo imprimirlos?

Tags: c++, array

profesor es mi clase con su constructor y funciona bien todo sin los vectores. Solo no se como usar la libreria vector. No se como declararlo bien.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Docente.h"
#include "Investigador.h"
#include "Profesor.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<Profesor *> profesor;
    
    Profesor p1("juan",33,"fisica");
    Profesor p2("pedro",33,"fisica");
    Profesor p3("antonio",33,"fisica");
    
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ni la menor idea de que es `p[i]`, ya que la variable que defines se llama `profesor`. En todo caso, esos son punteros, asi que tienes que usar el operador `->` para acceder a sus atributos. Que tal si nos indicas cual es el problema que te da y colocas suficiente codigo para reproducir tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir objetos, sobrecarga el operador de inyección en flujo de salida:

```
class Profesor
{
    string nombre;
    string asignatura;
    int edad;

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Profesor &);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Profesor &p)
{
    return o << p.nombre << " da clases de " << p.asignatura << " y tiene " << p.edad << " años";
}
```

Con esa sobrecarga, puedes enviar a `cout` objetos `Profesor`:

```
Profesor p1("juan",33,"fisica");
Profesor p2("pedro",33,"fisica");
Profesor p3("antonio",33,"fisica");

cout << p1 << '\n' << p2 << '\n' << p3;
```

Si quieres insertar objetos a un vector, **OLVIDATE DE USAR PUNTEROS**, los punteros no son objetos, tienes dos opciones:

1. Insertar directamente el objeto:

   ```
   std::vector<Profesor> profesor;
   //          ^^^^^^^^ <--- Instancia, NO PUNTERO.

   Profesor p1("juan",33,"fisica");
   Profesor p2("pedro",33,"fisica");
   Profesor p3("antonio",33,"fisica");

   // Insertar en vector
   profesor.push_back(p1);
   profesor.push_back(p2);
   profesor.push_back(p2);
   ```
2. Construirlo directamente dentro del vector (suponiendo que el objeto `Profesor` tenga constructor):

   ```
   std::vector<Profesor> profesor;
   //          ^^^^^^^^ <--- Instancia, NO PUNTERO.

   // Crear directamente en vector
   profesor.emplace_back("juan", 33, "fisica");
   profesor.emplace_back("pedro", 33, "fisica");
   profesor.emplace_back("antonio", 33, "fisica");
   ```